# Run 32 bit library on iPhone 5s 64 bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit, zbar-sdk, zbar

I'am using [zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) in my application. If I want to run it on my iPhone 5s with an 64 bit processor, I get the following errors:

[image: Trying to run on my iPhone 5s]

Is it possible to use the 32 bit library on a 64 bit device, because I don't think, the library is going to be updated.

Comment: Just remove the 64 bit build from your app, to do this go to your targets build settings. Here in the Architectures remove the `arm64`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem, but I need to build a 64-bit binary, so I can't use @rckoenes's solution

Comment: I have the same problem over here!

Comment: I used @rckoenes aproach, because i don't need 32-bit binary.

Comment: @Chris not possible to build for 64bit with 32bit Library unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the comments above. A 64bit iPhone application requires all constituent libraries and frameworks to be 64bit. You can't mix and match. Leaving an application 32bit is non-optimal long term since iOS has to keep two versions of the system libraries loaded (32 and 64) as soon as a single 32bit app is run. Hence, you don't want to be the last app to support 64bit!

You can check if your library contains 64bit code using lipo. For example, here's the SBJson framework in 32bit:

```
$ lipo -info SBJson.framework/SBJson 
Architectures in the fat file: SBJson.framework/SBJson are: armv6 armv7 i386
```

and with 64bit code

```
$ lipo -info SBJson.framework/SBJson
Architectures in the fat file: SBJson.framework/SBJson are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```

In the case of zbar, if it's not available you could always try compiling yourself from source.